# Printing a pair of static methods a user defined amount of times?

Tags: java

For my computer science class in school I have to write a java code that asks for user input for a number of figures on a totem pol. The output must be upto(might be smaller depending on the number) the specified number of figures. The output must have 1 eagle at the top and whale-human figures paired in order. This is what I have but when I input 2 the program prints 3 figures. Help?

`````````
import java.util.*; //For scanner.

/*
* The class Totem contains methods to print a totem pole
* with up to the amount of figures specified by the user.
* 1 eagle always on top of pole.
* Whale and human figures paired with human below whale.
*/
public class Totem {
    //Welcome to the main method.
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);//initiates new scanner.
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("This program displays a totem pole with the amount of figures you want!");
        System.out.println("How many figures do you want?");
        int numberOfFigures = console.nextInt();
        eagle();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFigures / 2; i++) {
            whaleHumanPair();
        }
    }

//Prints ASCII art of an eagle.
public static void eagle() {
    System.out.println("                      _--_");
    System.out.println("                     /   -)");
    System.out.println("                 ___/___|___");
    System.out.println("       ____-----///|     ||||~=---_____");
    System.out.println("     //~/////////~/|     |//|||\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
    System.out.println("   /////////////////|   |/////|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
    System.out.println("  /////~~~~~~~~~~~~\\ |.||/~~~~~~~~~~~~`\\\\\\\\\\ ");
    System.out.println(" //                /\\\\|\\\\                  \\\\");
    System.out.println("                  ///W^\\W\\");
    System.out.println("                 ////|||\\\\\\");
    System.out.println("                 ~~~~~~~~~~");
}
//Prints ASCII art of a whale.
public static void whale() {
    System.out.println(" .--------'```'----....,,______             _,");
    System.out.println("|                               `-------._./  \\");
    System.out.println("|                                             <");
    System.out.println("\\          .-'`'-.                             `");
    System.out.println(" \\          -.o_.     _                 -'`\\   /");
    System.out.println("  ``'--.._.-=-._    .'  \\        _,,--'`    ._(");
    System.out.println(" (^^^^^^^`___    '-. |    \\  ,,.-'");
    System.out.println("  ````````   `'--..___\\    |`");
    System.out.println("                      `-.,'");
}

//Prints ASCII art of a human.
public static void human() {
    System.out.println("                 ////|||\\\\\\\\");
    System.out.println("                //// ^ ^ \\\\\\\\");
    System.out.println("                ||/  @ @  \\||");
    System.out.println("                ||    \"    ||");
    System.out.println("                ||\\   -   /||");
    System.out.println("                ~~ `). .(' ~~");
    System.out.println("               /---'|   |---\\");
    System.out.println("             /'  ,  `\\-/'. ,  '\\");
    System.out.println("            (   \\ |.  ..  | /   )");
    System.out.println("             \\  _\\|  .  . |/_  /");
    System.out.println("              `(  >.  .   <  )'");
    System.out.println("                \" |  .  . | \"");
    System.out.println("                  |  .    |");
    System.out.println("                  |    .  |");
    System.out.println("                  | .    .|");
    System.out.println("                  |%%%%%%%|");
    System.out.println("                  __|#|#|__");
    System.out.println("                 (____|____)");   
}

public static void whaleHumanPair() {
    whale();
    human();
}
`````````

}

Comment: Eagle + Whale + Human = 3 figures. What is the problem?

Comment: Well, ... the for loop runs one time too often. What can you do to fix that?

Comment: @Henry How so? `numberOfFigures / 2 = 2 / 2 = 1`, so loop runs once

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but for an input of 2 OP just wants one figure (i.e. one eagle).

Comment: @Henry Or maybe an eagle and a whale only?

Comment: Well, this would be easier with input/output and maybe less ASCII ART ;) an [mcve] would show the problem

Comment: For an input of 2 I just want the eagle to print as the whale and human should only print as pairs. If I input 3 then an eagle whale and human should print.

Comment: Turn off your computer and get a piece of paper and pencil. Think about different values of user input and what should be printed. (I would use E, H, and W rather than take the time to write the full word for each figure.) Start at 1 and count from there. See if you can determine any patterns.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, 2 figures you want an eagle and a whale.

Only pairs of (whale, human) need to be in that order.

So, you should handle odds and evens in your loop.

```
int numberOfFigures = console.nextInt();
if (numberOfFigures > 0) {
    eagle();              // i == 0
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfFigures; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) { // odd, i == 1, 3, ...
            whale();
        } else {          // even, i == 2, 4, ...
            human();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One figure for the `eagle();` before the `for`, another two figures for one time of `whaleHumanPair`. Maybe you'll want to separate the pair.

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase of the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFigures / 2; i++) {
    whaleHumanPair();
}
```

When you give `numberOfFigures =2` as input, the loop executes 1 time for `i=0` and calls  `whaleHumanPair()` function which in turns `prints 2 figures` as you have mentioned in function:

```
public static void whaleHumanPair() {
    whale();
    human();
}
```